# Is there a way to get code completion working with the qt4ruby library?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I'm currently just starting into ruby development and decided that I'd like to use qt4ruby to develop my gui, however when I use RubyMine or Aptana studio, code completion fails to function.

I've tried this both on Windows (with gem qtbindings) and ubuntu 14.04/15.04.

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [Atom](https://atom.io/) a try.

Atom does code completion. It does not have the Qt syntax built in, but it suggests completions of code which is already in memory. 
And it does excellent syntax highlighting for ruby.